# Pass array on AJAX request using plain js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm passing an array on a POST request using jQuery, however I don't understand how to do the same with "vanilla" javascript. This is my jQuery:

```
    // Request using jQuery
$.ajax({type:'POST',url:'insert-user.php',data: {myArray: myArray},
success:function(data_response){
    console.log("jQuery, got data back, response: "+data_response);
}});
```

This is currently how I'm trying to do it with plain js:

```
// Request using plain js
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
        console.log("JS, got data back, response: "+xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("POST","insert-user.php",true);
xmlhttp.send({myArray: myArray});
```

Comment: You need to serialize the array. Here is an example http://stackoverflow.com/a/12187670/1973002

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
xmlhttp.send('myArray='+JSON.stringify(myArray));
```

At php side,

```
$array= json_decode($_POST['myArray']);
```

Comment: I did this, however I don't know how to decode it on my php file, I'm getting something like this: `Array ( [myArray] => {\"email\":\"lisandro.vaccaro@gmail.com\",\"first_name\":\"Lisandro\",\"last_nam‌​e\":\"Vaccaro\"} )` I tried json_decode and urldecode

Answer (score 2):

The `.send()` method accepts a string which is the POST data to be sent in the request. In jQuery, the `data` property allows you to pass an object (which you have), but behind the scenes, jQuery converts the object into a key/value pairs format.

This is the format that you must pass to `.send()` because it doesn't automatically convert objects into the key/value string.

For example, to send `myArray` with three elements:

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
xmlhttp.send('myArray[]=first&myArray[]=second&myArray[]=third');
```

Remember to include the header, to tell the server side which format you are sending POST data in.

A function to convert a simple 1 dimensional array to this format could look like:

```
function arrayToKeyValueString(name, arr){
    var str = name + '[]=';
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        arr[i] = encodeURIComponent(arr[i]);
    }

    str += arr.join('&' + name + '[]=');
    return str;
}

var myArray = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

console.log( arrayToKeyValueString('myArray', myArray) );
// outputs: myArray[]=one&myArray[]=two&myArray[]=three
```

When working with plain Javascript ajax, it's often easier to just JSON encode data and send the string instead of trying to build the key/value string.

```
xmlhttp.send('myArray=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(myArray)));
```

Comment: I tried to do this, I'm printing the $_POST variable on the requested file and logging it in the console. However I'm getting an empty array

Comment: See my edit - try adding the `Content-type` header to tell PHP that it's URL encoded key/value format.

Comment: thanks, I tested both options. (I had to modify the second one a bit to send an associative array). However on my PHP I ended up with something like this, which I don know how to decode: `Array
(
    [myArray] => {\"email\":\"lisandro.vaccaro@gmail.com\",\"first_name\":\"Lisandro\",\"last_name\":\"Vaccaro\"}
)` how can I turn it into a php array?

Comment: Try, `$phpObject = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['myArray']));`. You can then do `echo $phpObject->email;`.

Comment: The above will decode it to a PHP object. To get an array: `$phpArray = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['myArray']), true);` So you can do `echo $phpArray['email'];`.