# Javascript: postAjax doesn't post anything

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, post

Good Morning!

I am writing a small AJAX application, using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350377/how-to-make-an-ajax-request-to-post-json-data-and-process-the-response) function as a base, and php as serve side language.

here is the javascript code involved

```
var dati = {};
dati.nome = d.getElementById('nome').value;
dati.cognome = d.getElementById('cognome').value;
console.log(dati);
url = "post.php";
jsonToPost = dati;
console.log(url);

processResponse = function(responseText){
    console.log(responseText);
    d.getElementById('response').innerHTML = responseText;
}
_SU3.postAjax(url, processResponse, jsonToPost);
});
```

And here is my php code, just a post processor to test ajax

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['nome'])){

$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$cognome = $_POST['cognome'];
$data['nome'] = $nome;
$data['cognome'] = $cognome;

$data = json_encode($data);

echo $data;
} else {
    echo "Errore!";
}
?>
```

The response I get from the ajaxRequest is "Errore!", it means it's not posting anything to the script.

Am I missing any obvious mistake? Or there is something i'm doing completely wrong?

The _SU3.ajax() function (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350377/how-to-make-an-ajax-request-to-post-json-data-and-process-the-response) for reference) is working just fine, so i'm surprised it doesn't work

---edit to ad the firebug response---
I hope i posted the right thing

```
request headers:
POST /~francesco/post.php HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:16.0) Gecko/2010010 Firefox/16.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://localhost/~francesco/ajax.html
Content-Length: 26
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

[Screenshot](http://cl.ly/image/270z0l2n0A3E/Schermata%202013-01-22%20alle%2018.19.54.png)
 in the screen shot there are other informations.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the data being sent to the server using some sort of proxy, like fiddler?

Comment: Please post the fiddler response as well.  That's much more useful.  And what is _SU3.postAjax(url, processResponse, jsonToPost);?  Where is that derived from?

Comment: @JustinBicknell Can you suggest me a mac alternative to fiddler?

Comment: @DavidL _SU3.postAjax() is a function from the script i linked, it's here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350377/how-to-make-an-ajax-request-to-post-json-data-and-process-the-response

Comment: @FrancescoZaffaroni I can suggest Firebug, which is a plugin for Firefox.  It works almost as well as fiddler for watching http requests and has some nice debugging tools as well

Comment: @FrancescoZaffaroni As David suggested Firebug works, also chrome developer tools lets you inspect http requests

Comment: @DavidL I posted the httprequest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As puckipedia suggested, you need to encode the object you are sending as a query string.  The following method will create the parameter string based on the object passed in:

```
_SU3.postAjax = function(url, callback, data) {

   var parameters = '';

   for (var p in data){
     parameters  += p + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[p]) + '&';
   }

   var ajaxRequest = _SU3.getAjaxRequest(callback);
   ajaxRequest.open("POST", url, true);
   ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
   ajaxRequest.send(parameters);
}
```

The function suggested in the link you provided was assuming you were passing in JSON, not a js object.

Note: The server code you posted should interpret the data properly:

```
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
```

Comment: Thank you very much, And could you explain me why it worked for the user who posted the original question? ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350377/how-to-make-an-ajax-request-to-post-json-data-and-process-the-response?lq=1 )?

Comment: @FrancescoZaffaroni That method was assuming the data being passed in was already stringified... so the alternative would be to stringify your javascript object before calling the postAjax function, then parsing the json on the server

Answer (score 3):

You might want to replace the line:

```
ajaxRequest.send("data=" + encodeURIComponent(data));
```

In _SU3.postAjax to:

```
ajaxRequest.send(data);
```

And then send the third argument (jsonToPost) as a string like this:

```
"nome=arg1&cognome=arg2"
```

For example:

```
"nome="+d.getElementById("nome").value + "&cognome="+d.getElementById("cognome").value`
```

Comment: Thank you, but I really wanted to send JSON formatted data, just to keep everything tidy and nice looking, and to have more flexibility in integration with other code.

Comment: @FrancescoZaffaroni Your php code should work with the approach puckipedia suggested

Comment: @JustinBicknell The php code isn't important ;) it's just for test

Comment: @FrancescoZaffaroni in this case the php code is important, if you were using the method suggested by the link provided, your php would have had to parse the json string

Comment: @JustinBicknell And in your opinion which is the best method?

Comment: @FrancescoZaffaroni I like the solution that I provided. Keep in mind you can always pass a JSON string as an attribute of the object passed in, then parse that on the  server (if you need to)