# How can I return a PHP array to the javascript function that called it

Tags: php, javascript, html, html-parsing

..going to try this another way..

Links to another page are not very useful to me.. I've looked at most of them and have not been able to adapt them to what I need.

I'm not familiar with ajax or jQuery.

I could really use some help with detailed EXAMPLES of code that works with regard to this particular question. thanks in advance..

I have this piece of code called: JSON_generator.php

```
<?php
require_once 'EasyWebFetch.php';

$callback = isset($_GET['callback']) ? $_GET['callback'] : 'mymap.weatherhandler';
$station = isset($_GET['rid']) ? $_GET['rid'] : 'FWS';
$product = isset($_GET['product']) ? $_GET['product'] : 'NCR';
$nframes =  isset($_GET['frames']) ? $_GET['frames'] : 10;

if (strlen($product) != 3 || strlen($station) != 3) { exit; }

// fetch directory listing
$wf = new EasyWebFetch;
if (!$wf->get("http://radar.weather.gov/ridge/RadarImg/$product/$station/")) {
  print $wf->getErrorMessage();
  exit;
}
$page = $wf->getContents();
// echo $page."\n\n";

$size = preg_match_all( "/href=\"({$station}[\d_]+{$product}\.gif)\"/" , $page, $match);
$files = $match[1];

$nframes = min(count($files), $nframes);
$files = array_slice($files, -$nframes);

echo $callback."\n(\n{\ndirectory:\n[\n";
for ($i=0; $i < $nframes; $i++) {
  echo "\"ridge/RadarImg/$product/$station/$files[$i]\",\n";

}
echo "]\n}\n)\n;"

?>
```

When called from the command line like this...

```
http://example.com/mypath/JSON_generator.php?&?callback=CallBack&product=NCR&rid=JAX&frames=5
```

But what I really need is to have those .gif path/file/names "available" from a javascript function that called the php in the first place.** They need to be accessible as items in an array.

I can't figure out the javascript function call to do that..

.. something like this but obviously not this ..

```
function Feed (whichproduct, whichsite) {
 var filelist = [];
 var siteimages = filelist("http://example.com/mypath/JSON_generator.php?&product=whichproduct&rid=whichsite&frames=5");
..then..
//alert (filelist [1]); .. should return something like  "ridge/RadarImg/NCR/JAX/JAX_20130128_2354_NCR.gif"
}
```

Obviously, I'm a beginner so complete answers would be much more valuable to me than just code snippets..

Bottom line:

I need a javascript function that can pull each of those .gif names from the php script and bring them back into a javascript "var" that I can use elsewhere in the html file.

Thanks,
Dennis

edit.. edit removed.. figured it out..

Comment: Hi! Do you know about AJAX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) initially, since that makes things very easy, but I'll update in a moment with the vanilla Javascript implementation.

In your `Feed` function, make an AJAX call using jQuery's convenient `$.ajax` method.

```
function Feed (whichproduct, whichsite) {
    $.ajax({
        "url": "http://mysite.com/mypath/JSON_generator.php?&product=whichproduct&rid=whichsite&frames=5"
        "type": "GET",
        "dataType": "json",
        "success": function( data, status, xhr ){
            alert( data[1] );
        }
    });
}
```

In your PHP, use `json_encode` on a well-formed PHP array (just push to an `array()` instead of echoing the urls and commas and such directly).

At the very end, `print json_encode( $yourArray )`.

### Update for Vanilla Javascript:

Rather than copying the (extensive) javascript here, I'll just link to a nice [SO answer by @Richard H](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5351647/597122).  Hope that helps if you're not looking at using jQuery!

Comment: A vanilla JavaScript is what I was seeking. The example from Rihcard is more complex than I need. I don't need to write to a URL. My script will run from a smartphone..it needs to be small and fast. I think loading external libraries would slow it down?

Comment: ok... one typo later and some learning curve and that works.. hope it's as fast as the old way.. time will tell.. THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 0):

`json_encode($array);` is the way to go. The `json_encode` function write a JSON object for you to pass it to Javascript.

Then in Javascript you could install (if you aren't using it already) jQuery and parse the JSON string with [jQuery.parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) that returns a javascript object ready to use.

Answer (score 0):

To supplement the already posted answers, there are two problems here:

- Your response is not JSON, but JSONP - be sure to treat it that way. JSON looks like this: `{ ... }`, mimicking JSON's data structure, and is intended to be parsed; JSONP has a function call wrapped around it, and is intended to be executed: `callback({ ... })`.
- AJAX stands for Asynchronous JavaScript and XML. Not all parts of the acronym are still relevant, but asynchronicity is pretty big. This means you can't get the results of an AJAX call in the same function where you request it: you need to set up a callback, a function which will receive the results when they arrive.

Comment: Amadan, I don't understand.. are you saying the suggestions so far won't work?..please see my edited example for more detail. thanks.

Comment: @user1985512: They do work. I was giving additional explanation as to why yours didn't. Teach a man to fish, and all that.