# REST request or some other way to send basic authentication without challenge from IE

Tags: rest, internet-explorer, basic-authentication

I have posted this on superuser as well, but perhaps it will be easier to get correct answer from a developer here.

I am looking for a way to send a GET HTTPS request from Internet Explorer. I need to send basic authentication header even though the server does not challenge for it.

This is straightforward with Postman or a RESTClient add-on in Firefox, but I am constrained to use Internet Explorer only.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use angularJS. It seems powerful clientside for REST backend.

here is reference about compatibility with IE: 
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie

here is my example:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute', 'ngResource']);  

app.factory('RoomsResources', function ($resource) {

var auth_header = { 'Authorization': 'Basic ________[token auth]_____________'};

return $resource('https://[domain_name]/api/v1/rooms/:id', {id:'@id'}, {
    list:  { method: 'GET', isArray:true, headers: auth_header},
    get:  { method: 'GET', headers: auth_header},
    store: { method: 'POST', headers: auth_header},
    update: { method: 'PUT', headers: auth_header},
    destroy: { method: 'DELETE', headers: auth_header}
})});
```

You can also using vanilla javascript. In example you want to send GET request. Here is one question about this: 
[How to make an AJAX request to post JSON data and process the response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350377/how-to-make-an-ajax-request-to-post-json-data-and-process-the-response)

Just add header with

```
ajax.setRequestHeader('Authorization','Basic ________[token auth]_____________')
```

Here is one code that you can copy-paste for testing:

```
var xmlhttp=false;
/*@cc_on @*/
/*@if (@_jscript_version >= 5)
// JScript gives us Conditional compilation, we can cope with old IE versions.
// and security blocked creation of the objects.
try {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
} catch (e) {
    try {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (E) {
        xmlhttp = false;
    }
}
@end @*/
if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined') {
    try {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e) {
        xmlhttp=false;
    }
}
if (!xmlhttp && window.createRequest) {
    try {
        xmlhttp = window.createRequest();
    } catch (e) {
        xmlhttp=false;
    }
}

function getsomething(id) {
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readystate == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
            document.getElementById("something").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/"+id, true);
    xmlhttp.send(); 
}
```

Comment: I know very little `javascript` so still trying to make this work. The second link seems especially interesting but I still need to figure out how to actually send the request. Still this seems the right way to do it so accepting the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed example. I guess  I need to call `getsomething`? Can you please expand the example to say post the response from http://httpbin.org/headers with a single header, Header1/Value1?